# Is "False" in logic analogous to "Null set" in set theory?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

I have been doing proofs in elementary set theory, and so far, just using definitions (like below) and applying propositional logic has sufficed.

```
A ⋃ B = e ∈ A ∨ e ∈ B
A ⊂ B = e ∈ A ⟹ e ∈ B
A' = e ∉ A = ¬(e ∈ A)
```

So the proofs are as follows:

1. Convert set theory operations to their "logical" definitions
2. Shuffle the symbols using logical identities
3. Convert back from logic land to set theory land

**Here is my question**:

1. Is the logical analogous to the null set - Ø - the boolean false?
2. Is the logical analogous to the universal set - U - the boolean true?

More formally, are these definitions correct?

```
Ø = {e | false}
U = {e | true}
```

Here's my proof for: `A ⊂ B ⟹ A ⋂ B’ = Ø`, for example, where I use `false` for Ø:

```
A ⊂ B ⟹ A ⋂ B’ = Ø
≡ {Definition of Set Intersection and Subset, Definition of Ø}
[e ∈ A ⟹ e ∈ B] ⟹ [e ∈ A ∧ e ∈ B’ = false]
≡ {Exportation: A ⟹ [B ⟹ C] ≡ [A ∧ B] ⟹ C}
[e ∈ A ∧ e ∈ B] ⟹ [e ∈ A ∧ e ∈ B’ = false]

Context 1. e ∈ A
Context 2. e ∈ B

e ∈ A ∧ e ∈ B’
≡ {Context 1}
e ∈ B’ 
≡ {Definition of ‘}
¬(e ∈ B)
≡ {Context 2, Contradiction}
false
≡ {Definition of Ø}
Ø
```

Is the use of `false` for `Ø` valid in the proof above?

Comment: [Topos theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topos) might interest you.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks. I'll definitely check it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're basically right, but I'll flesh out a pedantic point. Identifying a set $S$ with the unary predicate $\varphi$ for which $\forall e(e\in S\iff\varphi(e))$, a set is $\emptyset$ is identified with *the unary $\varphi$ that always returns "false"*, **not** with "false" itself. (This is like confusing a constant function with the value it returns; it's a subtle distinction, but an easy one to make if e.g. you define a function as a certain kind of set of ordered pairs.) The usual choice for an explicit statement of this $\varphi$ is that $\varphi(e)$ iff $e\neq e$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I had asked a question about the set builder notation, where I learnt that $z \in \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \} \text {  iff  } \varphi (z)$. I should have written it as a constant function that returns false rather than false. itself

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are analogous.  You can show the analogy a bit more directly like this:

For boolean logic, we have:

$P \land \bot \Leftrightarrow \bot$  (or: $P\cdot 0 = 0$)

and

$P \lor \bot \Leftrightarrow P$ (or: $P+0=P$)

while for sets we have:

$P \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$

and

$P \cup \emptyset = P$

And yes, if you know that all the sets that you are working with are subsets of some 'universal' set $U$, you have:

$P \cap U = P$

and

$P \cup U = U$

just as in boolean logic you have:

$P \land \top \Leftrightarrow P$  (or: $P\cdot 1 = P$)

and

$P \lor \top \Leftrightarrow \top$ (or: $P+1=1$)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, this analogy makes sense. I just found out that in the wikipedia page for "Boolean Algebra" the first sentence says: "In abstract algebra, a Boolean algebra or Boolean lattice is a complemented distributive lattice. This type of algebraic structure captures essential properties of both set operations and logic operations." So that confirms that the relation between logic and set theory has been studied and proven formally.

Comment: @AtharvaShukla Exactly. As two-valued algebras they are exactly isomorph. Glad I could help!